# Java Generics as parameters

Tags: c#, java, generics

So I have a bunch of methods that essentially make the same call the only difference is class names of generics.  Example:

Current:

```
public void methodA(ARequest request, ADelegate delegate)
{
     JsonClient<ARequest, AResponse> client = new JsonClient<ARequest, AResponse>(request.ServiceServerUrl, request, new AResponse());
     client.sendRequest(delegate);
}

public void methodB(BRequest request, BDelegate delegate)
{
         JsonClient<BRequest, BResponse> client = new JsonClient<BRequest, BResponse>(request.ServiceServerUrl, request, new BResponse());
         client.sendRequest(delegate);
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
private void serviceCall<R extends RequestBase, S extends ResponseBase>(ADelegate delegate)
{
    JsonClient<R, S> client = new JsonClient<R, S>(request.ServiceServerUrl, request, new AResponse());
    client.sendRequest(delegate);
}

public void methodA(ARequest request, ADelegate delegate)
{
    serviceCall<ARequest, AResponse>(delegate);
}

public void methodB(BRequest request, BDelegate delegate)
{
    serviceCall<BRequest, BResponse>(delegate);
}
```

I think this is possible in C# but I just want to know how to properly do this in Java.

Edit:  For clarity.

Comment: don't understand what you really want. you method is void, and you don't used generics in params.. What you really want buddy?

Comment: Yeah reading back I guess it is unclear.  I have several classes that extend RequestBase.  One of them is ARequest.  I have several methods in a class like "method" that take the different child classes like ARequest and ADelegate as parameters.  So I just wanted to clean up my code a little bit and minimize cut and pasting.  I will edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write the following:

```java
private <R extends RequestBase, S extends ResponseBase> void serviceCall(
        R request,
        S response,
        ADelegate delegate
) {
    JsonClient<R, S> client = new JsonClient<R, S>(request.ServiceServerUrl, request, response);
    client.sendRequest(delegate);
}
```

Note that the caller must instantiate and pass in `response`, since something like `new S()` isn't possible in Java:

```java
public void method(ARequest request, ADelegate delegate) {
    serviceCall(request, new AResponse(), delegate);
}
```

Something like

```java
MyClass.<ARequest, AResponse>serviceCall(request, new AResponse(), delegate)
```

isn't necessary here because the compiler infers the type arguments for you.

Comment: Right now, `serviceCall` always takes an `ADelegate`. You could add a third type parameter `D extends DelegateBase` and have it take that instead if you wanted to fully generify the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
public <T extends RequestBase, E extends ResponseBase> void method(T request, E delegate)
{
     JsonClient<T, E> client = new JsonClient<T, E>(request.ServiceServerUrl, request, new AResponse());
     client.sendRequest(delegate);
}
```

and invoke it like `ClassName.<ARequest, AResponse>method(request, response)`.

Comment: Maybe something like `<T extends RequestBase, E extends ResponseBase> void method(T request, ADelegate delegate)`

Comment: I don't think `delegate` would be an `E`... that's the response type.